# PDF file sent as email attachment becomes corrupted (java)

Tags: java, email, pdf, email-attachments

I have a piece of code that attempts to send an email to a user and attach a pdf file. However, the attachment in the email received is always corrupted (simple files like txt files are fine). The original file is fine.

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("mailhost.example.com");
email.addTo("hello@example.com");
email.setFrom("hi@example.com", "hi");
email.setSubject("hello");
email.setMsg("hello");
File file = new File("file.pdf");
email.attach(file);
```

I have also tried using `EmailAttachment` instead of just a `File`, like so:

```
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setPath("path-to-file.pdf");
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setName("file.pdf");
email.attach(attachment);
```

In both cases, I receive an email with file.pdf attached, but when I open it, I get an error from Adobe Reader saying "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Stupid question but is file.pdf actually ok before you send it?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen it was the first thing I checked :) but yes, the file itself is fine.

Comment: Virus scanner somewhere in between (your code looks OK, that is why I follow this line of questioning)?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen It is Outlook and corporate, so most likely.

Comment: Open the file (as you got it in your e-mail) with an editor to check the header, check file size and see what is says.

Comment: it's about twice as big as the original 634kb to the original 362kb. @NorbertvanNobelen

Comment: It looks like the mime decode is not working. Run a manual mime decode to see what happens. Also send it to a gmail just to verify if outlook is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I suppouse that you are using `commons-email` dependency because you create a new instance of `EmailAttachment`. The problem is that the pdf file should be a `byte[]`. So you can try to implement using something like this:

```
email.attach(new org.apache.commons.mail.ByteArrayDataSource(pdfInBytes, "application/pdf"),
  "file.pdf", "PDF description", EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
```

This worked for me with `commons-email 1.1` dependency

Comment: is ByteArrayDataSource this one: javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource ?It was unable to send the email. I converted the pdf into bytes[] with Files.readAllBytes(); I am using apache.commons.mail

Comment: Nop, you should use `ByteDataSource` from `org.apache.commons.mail`